# mysql docker container get remote host: Connection refused after container running

Tags: mysql, docker, database-connection, docker-container

I tried to run multiple mysql docker container on one host server. After setting one first mysql container, it works fine. I following the same step to setting up second one and change the running port from 3306 to 3307 and use different path of dump.sql. After container starting up, I cannot telnet the container with container ip with port but i am able to ping the ip. It shows Connection refused.Trying to add the line bind-address=0.0.0.0 into /etc/my.cnf and restart container and the issue is still the same. I can see second mysql container start and I am able to execute some command on the container but after about 1 mins, the container stop automatically

```
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker run --name=test-db -p 3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass -v dump.sql:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
0e3fbcbd9126a726584549a13248eb07eb7d97fbeba4795fb5a924037a66b205
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
0e3fbcbd9126        mysql/mysql-server:5.7   "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   29 seconds ago      Up 28 seconds       33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3310->3306/tcp   test-db
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' test-db
172.17.0.4
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ telnet 172.17.0.4 3310
Trying 172.17.0.4...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ ping 172.17.0.4
PING 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- 172.17.0.4 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.037/0.042/0.053/0.009 ms
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
0e3fbcbd9126        mysql/mysql-server:5.7   "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3310->3306/tcp   test-db
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS                               NAMES
0e3fbcbd9126        mysql/mysql-server:5.7   "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute           33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3310->3306/tcp   test-db
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker exec test-db "exec mysql -h 172.17.0.4 -u user -p"
Error response from daemon: Container 0e3fbcbd9126a726584549a13248eb07eb7d97fbeba4795fb5a924037a66b205 is not running
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
usr@ip-172-0-1-199:~/$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                               NAMES
0e3fbcbd9126        mysql/mysql-server:5.7   "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 37 seconds ago                                       test-db
```

Comment: why are you trying to telnet into it?
You can run mysql admin tools by logging into the running container.
Eg: `docker exec -it test-db sh`

Comment: i did try to log into container `mysql -h 172.17.0.4 -u user -p` but i get `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 172.17.0.4 (111)
`

Comment: The subnet 172.17.0.x is likely only visible by containers and you're trying to access it through the 172.0.1.x subnet. Print out your `docker network ls` and also try to start your mysql console directly using `docker exec -it test-db mysql -u user -p`

Answer (score 0):

Set `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%` to allow root login from any IP.

```
docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 \
-e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
```